# Is it possible to stylize a tooltip with WIN32 API and GDI+ (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, styles, tooltip, gdi

I'm writing down some code and I would like to warn the user about wrong moves using a tooltip. The max I can achieve using WIN32 `<commctrl.h>`
TOOLINFO structure is a classic rectangular tooltip on a single line. The result I'd like to reach is something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this using GDI+ and WIN32 API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth I don't think that's a tooltip, but rather a custom control (or just a custom element in the game board) formatted a specific way. The uxtheme APIs can give you the system theme appearance and fonts and colors.

Answer (score 2):

To split your tooltip text onto multiple lines, send the control a [`TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760408(v=vs.85).aspx) message to give it a maximum width. It will then wrap text automatically, or you can use `\r\n` to insert line breaks manually. This is described in detail here: [How to Implement Multiple Line Tooltips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298403(v=vs.85).aspx).

Use the [`TTM_SETTITLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760414(v=vs.85).aspx) message to give your tooltip a title and an icon.

Comment: That's a good tip but I still won't be able to customize my tooltip font color or use images inside it. Do you think I'd have to give up in my attempt of giving it a style?

Comment: You didn't ask that in your question, but no - the tooltip control can't do that itself. You'd have to use custom draw.